# CSS Responsive Grid with transparent backgrounds and centered text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid

Trying for hours to get a responsive Grid with semi transparent backgrounds and **horizontal and vertical** centered text to work. Everything works, except the centered text and background overlay to darken the background-image!

This is one Grid item:

```
<article class="grid-box">
    <div class="grid-wrapper">
        <div class="grid-content">
            <div class="grid-background">
                <header>
                   <h2>Main</h2>
                   <h3>Sub</h3>
                </header>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

The CSS:

```
.grid-box {
    width:33.33%;
    max-width:400px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.grid-box .grid-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
}

    .grid-box .grid-wrapper .grid-content {
    background: url(https://www.dennisjauernig.com/wp-content/uploads/getting-ready-hochzeitsfotos-hochzeitsfotograf.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;  
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    padding-bottom:67%;
    width:100%;
    height:0;
}

.grid-box .grid-wrapper .grid-content:hover{
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);  
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);  
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);  
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.grid-background{
    background:url(https://www.dennisjauernig.com/wp-content/themes/selfmade/images/transparent05.png);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dz2f83sz/ .
And live here as a test: https://www.dennisjauernig.com/berlin-hochzeitsfotos2/

Comment: Okay, got it to work in Firefox & Chrome. But Safari ignores the vertical-align:middle. Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/dz2f83sz/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centering verticaly is always difficult (except for tables).

- Set the position of the .grid-content to relative.
- Set the .grid-background  to "display: table;", height and width to
  100% and the position to absolute.

Then add the followinf style to the header:

```
.grid-background header{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dz2f83sz/5/

Answer (score -1):

```css
header{
    text-align:center;
}
.grid-box {
        width:100%;
        max-width:400px;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -o-box-sizing:border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    .grid-box .grid-wrapper {
     overflow: hidden;
        width:100%;
    }

        .grid-box .grid-wrapper .grid-content {
        background: url(https://www.dennisjauernig.com/wp-content/uploads/getting-ready-hochzeitsfotos-hochzeitsfotograf.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;  
        -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
        padding-bottom:67%;
        width:100%;
        height:0;
    }

    .grid-box .grid-wrapper .grid-content:hover{
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);  
        -o-transform: scale(1.1);  
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);  
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }

    .grid-background {
        background:url(https://www.dennisjauernig.com/wp-content/themes/selfmade/images/transparent05.png);
    }
```

```html
<article class="grid-box">
        <div class="grid-wrapper">
            <div class="grid-content">
                <div class="grid-background">
                    <header>
                       <h2>Main</h2>
                       <h3>Sub</h3>
                    </header>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Comment: Thanks Adi! But this is just horizontal. :)